# How can I keep every fifth row in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, database, macros, vba, manipulation

I have a data set in excel with 3084 rows. I need to delete 4 rows, then keep one: deleting Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday but keeping Monday to create a *weekly* rather than *daily* data set.

- Note: The data is *coinciding with a date* **not a day of the week** so I cant simply filter out Tuesdays and so forth [the date appears as **14-Jun-00**]).

Is there any way to do this without having to manually go through and delete four rows at a time?

Answer (score 8):

Choose a nearby column and write `=MOD(ROW(A1),5)` on the first row. This will fill all rows in that column with numbers 0-4. Then simply autofilter  out rows you want to delete:
`Data > Filter > AutoFilter`

**Edit:** Since it's a recurring date you could probably also just use a [wildcard when filtering](http://www.contextures.com/xladvfilter01.html), ie `14-*`

Comment: Perhaps a variation - try WEEKDAY function, e.g. =WEEKDAY(A1) in adjacent column, then filter by 2 in that column (monday = 2)

Comment: Aaron, be sure to uptick this answer then to make it the "Accepted" answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try a VBA solution - may need to make minor modifications based on your problem but this gives the general idea. This subroutine assumes that you the first cell in the first row is activated, and then the subroutine is run.

```
Sub sbDelete4Keep1()

    Dim rngProcess As Range
    Dim lCntr As Long
    Set rngProcess = ActiveCell
    lCntr = 1
    While Not IsEmpty(rngProcess.Offset(1, 0))
        Range(rngProcess, rngProcess.Offset(3, 0)).EntireRow.Delete
        Set rngProcess = ActiveCell.Offset(lCntr, 0)
        lCntr = lCntr + 1
    Wend

End Sub
```